# positioned elements not being placed correctly & z-index not working

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, css-position

Weird one: on my site, the position works, but the mouseover and z-indexes don't.  On fiddle, the mouseover works, but the position doesn't.

Is there some CSS setting that I'm missing that causes jQuery not to be able to select?

I'm hoping it's just bad code or some nuance I'm not aware of.

Many thanks in advance!

**html**

```
<div style="text-align: center; position: relative">
    <span id="selectSupplierNameSpan" style="z-index:100">
        Vendor
    </span>
    <div id="selectSupplierNameContainer" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index:50">
        <input type="text" id="selectSupplierName" ></input>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#selectSupplierNameContainer").position({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: $("#selectSupplierNameSpan"),
});

$("#selectSupplierNameSpan").mouseover(function() {
    var thisHeight = $("#selectSupplierNameContainer").height();
    $("#selectSupplierNameContainer").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: "+=" + thisHeight
    }, 500);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7s4VN/10/

**EDIT**

Went to jquery 1.7.2, and added ui 1.18, and now the mouseover doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to be using the [jQuery-UI version of `.position()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position#overview). Your fiddle doesn't.

Comment: Are you using the same browser to view both the fiddle and your site?

Comment: Your jsFiddle has your markup correct, but your code above is missing a closing tag for your outer div... is that just a typo, here, or is that cut and pasted from your original source?

Comment: @blazemonger woops.  i'll add jquery-ui and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` can only be applied to positioned elements. Add `position:relative;` to the styles for your `<span>` and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7s4VN/11/

Comment: Incidentally, there's no such thing as a closing `</input>` tag -- you can safely remove that from your HTML.

Comment: i love css people.  Thanks all!